# What's created this key combo?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks

I've recently upgraded my iMac to OSX Mavericks. I'm finding that when I press Control-Shift-N something is immediately locking my screen and making it dark. I can still hear my streaming audio playing, so I guess it's not logging me out. I've looked carefully through the list of keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences, and that key combo isn't mentioned anywhere.

Is there any place I can get a list of all active keyboard shortcuts? Is there any terminal command I can run to see which application has taken over this keypress combination? It's really annoying because I habitually use that combo in PHPStorm! (And yes, I have checked the keymaps there too.)

Comment: Do you mean "Command-Shift-N"?

Comment: Nay, it's Ctrl-Shift-N - Ctrl the key in the bottom left corner.

Comment: But you are using a mac?

Comment: OH wait, I was thinking of the Windows key, never mind you are right...

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) that will show you all the key combos your current running app.

Comment: Thanks VPL, that looks a very promising app - unfortunately I'm struggling to get it to work on my machine - the cheatsheet is popping up and instantly disappearing when I hold down Option.

Comment: Oh, got it - if I keep on holding down Option it eventually stays visible. Thanks a lot! This is the sort of thing I need. Unfortunately it's not showing me the combo I'm looking for, so I'll see if anybody can suggest any alternative before ticking this.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you have ctrl-shift-n acting like ctrl-shift-eject would.